# Aggregate dados no R com função própria

Tags: r, regressão

Gostaria de obter o R² fazendo a regressão linear para cada agrupamento do meu banco de dados. Meu código esta assim, mas não consigo rodar.

```
x <- dados$area.ACM 
y <- dados$Largura 
model <- lm(log(y)~log(x)) 
novosdados <- aggregate(dados, by = list(rotulo = dados$Rótulos.de.Linha), FUN = model)
```

### Meus dados:

```
dados
              Categoria ORDEM area.ACM Largura
1                   0     1    90.10    3.78
2                   0     2   239.20   13.61
3                   0     3   639.62   22.21
4                   0     4  1104.40   28.85
5                   0     5  1665.04   28.69
6                   0     6  2266.62   33.95
7                   0     7  3109.09   45.40
8                   0     8  3975.05   45.76
9                   0     9  4936.68   49.43
10                  0    10  5999.67   57.04
11                  0    11  7145.59   57.45
12                  0    12  8265.30   50.14
13                  0    13  9241.26   48.64
14                  0    14 10096.26   43.93
15                  0    15 11178.55   57.80
16                  0    16 12469.35   69.46
17                  0    17 13835.76   67.89
18                  0    18 15005.12   59.41
19                  0    19 16204.52   57.11
20                  1     1   333.22   21.72
21                  1     2   755.98   23.24
22                  1     3  1148.70   15.46
23                  1     4  1483.86   23.16
24                  2     1   188.40    9.76
25                  2     2   381.31    9.73
26                  2     3   586.00   11.37
27                  2     4   860.24   20.45
28                  2     5  1267.64   18.74
29                  2     6  1599.34   11.66
30                  2     7  1924.61   23.68
31                  2     8  2478.65   33.26
32                  2     9  3125.11   30.71
33                  2    10  3795.50   32.33
34                  2    11  4412.67   34.42
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados, 20))`?

Comment: Depois de ter editado a sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/551657/regress%c3%a3o-n%c3%a3o-linear-para-cada-agrupamento-de-dados-no-r) com os dados, ficou muito melhor e muito melhor que esta versão. Ponha aqui os dados tal como pos lá mas em vez do `>` antes de `dados`, formate-os como código.

Comment: Obrigada pela edição!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quer apenas os valores de R² por categoria, sem armazenar as listas com o resultado das regressões, pode se valer da lógica "separa/aplica" (split/apply). Pacotes `dplyr` e `data.table` facilitam esse tipo de operação.

### Com data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados[, .(r.squared = summary(lm(log(area.ACM) ~ log(Largura)))$r.squared), Categoria]
#>    Categoria  r.squared
#> 1:         0 0.88588363
#> 2:         1 0.04933031
#> 3:         2 0.78306697
```

### Com dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>% group_by(Categoria) %>%
  summarise(r.squared = summary(lm(log(area.ACM) ~ log(Largura)))$r.squared)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Categoria r.squared
#>       <int>     <dbl>
#> 1         0    0.886
#> 2         1    0.0493
#> 3         2    0.783
```

### R base

```
reslm <- lapply(split(dados, dados$Categoria),
  function(x) summary(lm(log(area.ACM) ~ log(Largura), x))$r.squared)
#> $`0`
#> [1] 0.8858836
#>
#> $`1`
#> [1] 0.04933031
#>
#> $`2`
#> [1] 0.783067
```

## Dados

```
dados <- structure(list(Categoria = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ORDEM = c(1L, 2L, 3L,
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L,
    18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L,
    10L, 11L), area.ACM = c(90.1, 239.2, 639.62, 1104.4, 1665.04,
    2266.62, 3109.09, 3975.05, 4936.68, 5999.67, 7145.59, 8265.3,
    9241.26, 10096.26, 11178.55, 12469.35, 13835.76, 15005.12, 16204.52,
    333.22, 755.98, 1148.7, 1483.86, 188.4, 381.31, 586, 860.24,
    1267.64, 1599.34, 1924.61, 2478.65, 3125.11, 3795.5, 4412.67),
    Largura = c(3.78, 13.61, 22.21, 28.85, 28.69, 33.95, 45.4,
    45.76, 49.43, 57.04, 57.45, 50.14, 48.64, 43.93, 57.8, 69.46,
    67.89, 59.41, 57.11, 21.72, 23.24, 15.46, 23.16, 9.76, 9.73,
    11.37, 20.45, 18.74, 11.66, 23.68, 33.26, 30.71, 32.33, 34.42
    )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
    -34L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55c3543ae220>)
```

Comment: Obrigada pelas opções de resolução!

Answer (score 5):

Eis uma solução. Mas com a função [`by`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html), não com `aggregate`.

A função `by` divide a tabela por `Categoria` e aplica o `lm` a cada sub-base `x`. Depois o ciclo `lapply` cria uma lista de sumários, onde se incluem os R2. Finalmente, extraem-se os R2 e usam-se esses valores para extrais os modelos com R2 acima de 0.85 (ou outro valor).

```r
x <- '              Categoria ORDEM area.ACM Largura
1                   0     1    90.10    3.78
2                   0     2   239.20   13.61
3                   0     3   639.62   22.21
4                   0     4  1104.40   28.85
5                   0     5  1665.04   28.69
6                   0     6  2266.62   33.95
7                   0     7  3109.09   45.40
8                   0     8  3975.05   45.76
9                   0     9  4936.68   49.43
10                  0    10  5999.67   57.04
11                  0    11  7145.59   57.45
12                  0    12  8265.30   50.14
13                  0    13  9241.26   48.64
14                  0    14 10096.26   43.93
15                  0    15 11178.55   57.80
16                  0    16 12469.35   69.46
17                  0    17 13835.76   67.89
18                  0    18 15005.12   59.41
19                  0    19 16204.52   57.11
20                  1     1   333.22   21.72
21                  1     2   755.98   23.24
22                  1     3  1148.70   15.46
23                  1     4  1483.86   23.16
24                  2     1   188.40    9.76
25                  2     2   381.31    9.73
26                  2     3   586.00   11.37
27                  2     4   860.24   20.45
28                  2     5  1267.64   18.74
29                  2     6  1599.34   11.66
30                  2     7  1924.61   23.68
31                  2     8  2478.65   33.26
32                  2     9  3125.11   30.71
33                  2    10  3795.50   32.33
34                  2    11  4412.67   34.42'

dados <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)


model_list <- by(dados, dados$Categoria, FUN = \(x) lm(log(Largura)~log(area.ACM), x))
smry_list <- lapply(model_list, summary)
rsq <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, 'r.squared')
rsq
#>          0          1          2 
#> 0.88588363 0.04933031 0.78306697

model_list[rsq > 0.85]
#> $`0`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = log(Largura) ~ log(area.ACM), data = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   (Intercept)  log(area.ACM)  
#>      -0.03155        0.44718
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Otimo! Solucao simples e eficiente! Muito obrigada

Comment: Tentei extrair o valor do Coeficiente 'log', da mesma forma. Alterei apenas a linha a seguir: expoente <- sapply(smry_list, `[[`, 'log') Mas nao funcionou

Comment: @Clarissa Para extrair os dois coeficientes tente `lapply(model_list, coef)`. Ou `sapply`, para ter uma matrix de coeficientes.